# Change stacking order of charts in c3.js

Tags: c3.js

By default in c3.js Area charts are indexed above other charts like bar charts. How can I change stacking order of c3.js charts?

Comment: Is this still an issue? What do you mean exactly? Do you mean the order they appear on the page? You can change that by giving each chart and div its own id, and then bind to each id

Comment: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1938